# Puppet: Multiple Instances with Different Parameters

Tags: class, include, puppet

I am running a server with a wiki, which is provisioned using Puppet. Here's a simplified version of my `wiki` class:

```
class wiki($name, $repo, $username, $password) {
    # details omitted
}
```

I am using it currently as follows:

```
class profiles::my_wiki_server {
    class { 'wiki' :
        name => 'wiki',
        repo => 'wiki',
        username => 'admin',
        passowrd => 'topsecret'
    }
}
```

This works fine. Now I want to run a second wiki (let's call it `jokes`) on the same server. Unfortunately, using another `class { 'wiki' :` declaration doesn't work, as I saw it already documented in other questions.

So my workaround is to create two classes:

```
class wiki($name, $repo, $username, $password) {
    # details omitted
}

class wiki::default($name, $repo, $username, $password) {
    include wiki
}

class wiki::jokes($name, $repo, $username, $password) {
    include wiki
}
```

I can use those as follows:

```
class profiles::my_wiki_server {
    class { 'wiki::default' :
        name => 'wiki',
        repo => 'wiki',
        username => 'admin',
        passowrd => 'topsecret'
    }
    class { 'wiki::jokes' :
        name => 'jokes',
        repo => 'jokes',
        username => 'admin',
        passowrd => 'topsecret'
    }
}
```

However, when I do so, the variables are not set (Error: `expects a value for parameter 'name'` etc.).

Is there a way to set those variables so that the original `wiki` class can use them?

Comment: This sounds a lot more like you want a defined resource type for `wiki` instead of a class.

Comment: Creating two classes to (only) wrap the same one class seems unlikely to get you where you want to be.  Class `wiki` still only has *one* set of parameters (that you presently are not specifying).  Yours is not a syntax problem, but rather a design problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use a defined type rather than a class.

Defined types are documented at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_defined_types.html.

The short version is that, rather than

```
class wiki ($name, $repo, $username, $password) {
    # details omitted
}
```

you want

```
define wiki ($name, $repo, $username, $password) {
    # details omitted
}
```

You can then use the defined type as many times as you want:

```
class profiles::my_wiki_server {
    wiki { 'wiki':
        name => 'wiki',
        repo => 'wiki',
        username => 'admin',
        passowrd => 'topsecret'
    }

    wiki { 'wiki::jokes':
        name => 'jokes',
        repo => 'jokes',
        username => 'admin',
        passowrd => 'topsecret'
    }
}
```